# Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device

Tags: android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I have successfully downloaded and installed Genymotion and Virtualbox as well as a Virtual Device Image but I am unable to create a virtual device.
I get an error message stating

> Unable to create Virtual Device: 
>   Failed to import OVA

My laptop Specs
8gb RAM
Intel Core i7 (Sandy Bridge)
Hardware Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I am stupid.It works fine running the genymotion with administrative privileges.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, then mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: Why would Genymotion need to be run with Admin privileges?  That is not a documented requirement on the Genymotion website...

Comment: use freegate and set proxy in genymotion setting :127.0.0.1 port:8580

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved the problem.It was my mistake.
It works fine by running genymotion with administrative privileges.

Comment: Doesn't seem like one should need to run Genymotion as an admin

Comment: I cant get it to work without that.I got UAC disabled as well.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's a Windows requirement (I'm on Linux/OS X)

Comment: I ran with admin privileges, reinstalled... but continues not working here.

Comment: As per documentation, it is not necessary or advisable to run software under privileged credentials. Check links for install instructions from manufacturer.
  
[install on windows](https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/Get_started/011_Windows_install)  
  
[install on linux](https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/Get_started/013_Linux_install/)

Answer (score 50):

Deleting the Genymotion cached .ova file, deleting the corrupted deployed image, redownloading the image, and reinstalling it addressed the issue for me.

Note that the deployed images are under:
~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed

the cached ova files are under:
~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova

Comment: This helped for me, thnx!

Comment: i CAN'T FIND THE FILES.....Can you pls help....there is no folder named deployed even though i hav 5 devices installed.

Comment: try ~\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\ instead if you don't have ~\.Genymobile\

Comment: I delete .Genymobile folder and reinstall the Genymobile and even delete everything in Virtual Box VMS. But still get the same problem

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava  It depends what operating system you are on.  If you are on a Mac of Linux, you can use the 'locate' command in the terminal to search for *.ova files.

Comment: ~/.Genymodile removal helped me

Comment: this is the best answer for Linux/OSX

Comment: The problem occurs when you delete a VM from Genymotion and Virtual Box but it doesn't actually get deleted from ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed so all you need to do is manually go to that directory and delete the folder that is causing you issues :)

Comment: I just removed the whole directory `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Genymobile`

Answer (score 19):

I solved the issue deleting the deployed images in

~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed

I didn't touch ova files

Comment: I do not have the deployed folder...how can that be solved?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this problem too, so just in case anyone needs it:
The reason why it needs admin privileges is probably because of your settings on where it store the virtual device.. 
Go to Settings - Virtual Box - and change your virtual devices storage area. I got mine set to something like \Program Files\Genymotion, that's why it needs Admin privileges. I only blanked the field, clicked ok, and it got set to the default which is in my home directory..
After that no need to run as admin anymore..

(I need 50 reputations to comment, so had to use this answer..)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue myself by deleting all old devices (the folders of previously made devices) from my .android/avd folder.

Comment: This is the one that did it for me. I had issues after upgrading to Mavericks with the Google Nexus 5. Wiping out only ~/.Genymobile wasn't working so I removed both ~/.Genymobile and ~/.android. After Redownloading it was able to work. Thanks Ben

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the DHCP server was missing from Virtual Box's Host Only Adapter. I added a DHCP server at 192.168.56.100 with addresses from 192.168.56.101 - 192.168.56.254 and it came up.

Comment: Same here, I had to do the above step, it should be there by default, no idea why.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the issue. Had to delete Genymotion cached files/devices then redownload devices and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issues, it was because we had wrong version of  Oracle VM Virtual Box. Make sure you uninstall wrong version and re-install Compatible Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Comment: This was it for me. As of now *To run virtual devices, you must install Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.4 or above. Genymotion might work with older versions of Oracle VM VirtualBox but we cannot guarantee it.* https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Requirements.htm

Answer (score 3):

just delete the file in your ova and it should fix it, thats what i did, no need to run program under admin or anything. didnt delete my deployed files either. (I was trying to create new virtual machines not open them)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this blog](http://androvm.org/blog/).

Genymotion is previously known as AndroidVM.

As the blog stated:

```
Known bugs (same as 20121119 release) :

Hardware OpenGL/Intel HD/Windows : On most Intel HD drivers running Windows, the AndroVMplayer might crash (in the driver DLL) when starting Android ; you may have to restart AndroVMplayer an important number of times before it suceeds
Hardware OpenGL/WebView : On some GPUs (mostly NVidia ?), the browser and all apps which use the WebView component might show scrambled HTML content
AndroVMplayer now support window resizing, as well as fullscreen mode ; to use AndroVMplayer in fullscreen mode, you have to :

select “manual resolution” and tick the “fullscreen” box
press F11 (Ctrl+F11 on Mac) to switch to fullscreen when the player window has appeared
When starting the virtual machine, AndroVMplayer now check different things :

If your AndroVM virtual machine doesn’t have the “hardware OpenGL” option enabled, it can enable it for you before starting the VM.
If your AndroVM virtual machine first network adapter is not configured, it can configure it for you (as well as create the host-only network for you).
To summarize that, with this new AndroVMplayer, to use OpenGL hardware you just have to :

Import the AndroVM ova in VirtualBox
Start AndroVMplayer, choose your resolution and the virtual machine you’ve just imported
Click “Run” and it should work
You can still use AndroVMplayer with non-VirtualBox systems (e.g VMWare) but, obviously, you won’t benefit from automatic VirtualBox configuration and VM start/stop ; in this case, you have to choose ‘none’ as the VM name and directly type the IP address of your virtual machine.

Please note that, due to the change in communication, old AndroVMplayer won’t work with 20130222 OVAs and old OVAs won’t work with 20130222 AndroVMplayer.
```

Comment: I am stupid.It works fine running the app with administrative privileges.

Comment: Must forgot!! you have to run it with administrative privileges!! Glad you find out the solution with yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Disadvantage of deleting the deployed and .ova files is obvious i.e. you have to download the massive 200mb image again. A better choice is to :

- Open genymotion and open settings --> virtualBox --> virtual devices browse and set the path to a folder which can be completely accessed without administrative pivileges e.g. for ubuntu set virtual devices path to any folder in your home directory for example /home/user/deployed and for windows you can use a folder like C://deployed.

That's it . Now you can use your already existing .ova file again to deploy image to new locatioin without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I followed following steps

1. I removed everything under {~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova} folder (with only doing this step it works sometimes)
2. removed everything under {~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/bin} folder

After which I downloaded the fresh copy and it worked like magic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error message by fixing the path to the virtual machines folder (Setting > VirtualBox - Virtual devices). Yes, I had broken settings...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is using Mac OSX YOSEMITE or earlier. Follow this post. It worked for me. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1196027

Run these two command in Terminal:

## sudo chmod 755 /Applications

## sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Virtualbox.app

Took me hours to get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you have problem with your virtual device path under 
   **Genymotion > Settings > Virtual Box > Virtual Device >**

[image]

2. If it is still an issue remove files under **~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova**
3. If it is still an issue remove files under **~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/bin**
4. Remove Genymotion and all files under **~/.Genymobile/** & reinstall

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have installed the Genymotion plugin without VirtualBox then make sure the **version** of VBox is *compatible* with the plugin, otherwise the plugin will not deploy the virtual device regardless of the OVA file.Install the latest versions of both if you are unsure
2. Once you verified the versions, you may need to either:

   a: Give administrative privileges for Genymotion via properties

   **OR**

   b: Change the location for the deployed devices via Settings/VirtualBox to somewhere more accessbile like D:/GenyMotion VMs/
3. If both step 1 and 2 doesnt work for you, sadly you will have to clear the cache via Settings/Misc and reinstall the OVA file.Hopefully your efforts will be worth it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine by running genymotion with administrative privileges.

I solved it by deleting all of file in Ova,Templates and Deployed folder, I can run download and reinstall again and run without Administrative privileges

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on windows setting up sdk path in configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the virtual device you're trying to create has the same version on Genymotion that you have running.

I just upgraded to 2.1.1 but all the virtual devices I was trying to install were for 2.1.0. Downgrading Genymotion did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple Solution that i just Tried is:

1) Delete your Instalation Folder at ~/Genymobile

2) Delete the Virtual Device Folder at C:\Users\ your_name\AppData\Local/Genymobile

3) Reinstall

4) Done.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle VM ware has an update for Windows 10.  I was getting this error until I installed this update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because i had an **old version** of **Virtual Box (4.0.0)**.
So, I **uninstalled** genymotion and the old version of VB, 
and I installed **genymotion** with **virtual box (5.0.28)**.

 And Its worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

1. Just go to `~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova` (Either you are on Mac OSX
   or Windows, you can find this path by looking for Virtualbox path at
   the Genymotion Settings, there is a path to Genymotion/deployed
   folder, you should go to Genymotion/ova folder)
2. Open the ova file with your virtualbox.
3. At the Virtualbox startup dialog box, Appliance settings, It shows `Guest OS` type set to `Other Linux 64`, you should double click and change it to your OS type (e.g Mac OSX El Captain (64-bit)) and Import:
   [image]
4. Now launch Genymotion and find the virtual device in the list of already deployed ones ready to run
5. Run the virtual device, after first run you get a warning saying Genymotion version does not match with Virtualbox version and choose Continue.

I hope it helps future visitors to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Any of above solutions didn't work for me but I finally found it!

You should remove under folders in `C:\Users\[your user]\VirtualBox VMs`.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

First you go to ova inside the folder and delete all files

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\ova
```

After you uninstall the genymotion and virtual box. next you can do for install of genymotion and virtual box as check your support your OS(windows) capability version install then work fine.

Now you can create virtual device.

This way for work my windows 10 OS.

Comment: Thanks, now I need to redownload 12GB of data.

Answer (score -5):

Solved!!

I am using OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), Genymotion v1.3.1

While adding the device, instead of adding Nexus, I added Galaxy S4/HTC One/Xperia Z - 4.2.2 with Google Apps.

This one just worked.