# Geny motion failed to import OVA

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation, genymotion

Suddenly, i lost all Geny motion emulators (maybe after upgrading to Geny motion 2.2, not sure) and when ever i download a new virtual machine or emulator i get the "failed to import OVA" error and i can't use the virtual machines i downloaded at all in Geny motion, however they work in virtual box!

and i have cleared the cache and deleted old OVAs and re-downloaded other emulators again and again, but it's no use!

any clue what's going on?

is there a way to re-import emulators i already downloaded by Geny motion to Geny motion again instead of keeping downloading new emulators and getting the same error?

Comment: did any of the solutions below work for you?

Answer (score 85):

I solved the problem for myself. In my case, I had the same problem after defragmenting my computer. Deleting the ova and deploying files did not work (neither did reinstalling help). Solved it by clearing the cache in the app itself:

Settings>Misc>Cache Usage>Clear Cache

Try to see if that helps. If it doesn't then I can't help.

Comment: Dude, it deleted the downloaded ova file :-( I'm  on a low speed connection

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 16):

So I upgraded to the latest version of Genymotion 2.6.0. Tried to install the new Virtual Devices and I got the same error.
I tried to clear the cache as suggested above but it didn't help instead it removed the downloaded .ova file of the device and I had to download again.

I checked for update on VirtualBox and it shows that you're on the latest build. I checked the version and it showed 4.2.x.
Checked the latest version on the site and damn... It was version 5.0 available on the website.
Upgraded the VirtualBox to the latest 5.0 and here you go... Everything was back in place and my Genymotion Virtual Device was imported and is running fine.

So do check the versions of VirtualBox and see if it is the latest available on the website.

Comment: God damn it, hey guys you have done me a great service! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried everything, remove cache, reinstall. finally this answer helps! thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Deleting the Genymotion cached .ova file, deleting the corrupted deployed image, redownloading the image, and reinstalling it addressed the issue for me.

Note that the deployed images are under: ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed

the cached ova files are under: ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova

this link : [Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540311/unable-to-create-genymotion-virtual-device)

---

**Update :**

Settings>Misc>Cache Usage>Clear Cache

Comment: OK - i try too,but not work,finally i uprate virtualBox to new version and it work correctly :) - please try this.

Comment: i have the latest version and it still has a problem...i think it's mostly a network problem...because when i changed my laptop location i found 2 android VMs appeared in geny motion

Comment: @user2469133 probably the Genymotion image corrupted?

Comment: @EnriqueDiaz , your point is virtualbox files? - in this example address : user/AppData/Local/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Galaxy S4 - 4.3 - API 18 - 1080x1920

Answer (score 10):

Try to upgrade [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to the latest release, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Interesting. If works through VirtualBox, then I suggest you:
a) Re-install GenyMotion, hopefully installing the newest version or
b) If you're using Eclipse or Android Studio, re-install the plugin.

Comment: i would like to inform you that i have re-installed and in some cases re-downloaded everything from scratch and this problem , still exists!!!

Comment: It said VirtualBox is already up-to-date, so I had to uninstall it completely first. Upgrading VirtualBox from 4.x to 5.x helped.

Comment: Exactly as @ernazm said: my VBox version was 4.1. Uninstall, download v5 from VBox site and all fixed.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

Some VirtualBox version are not compatibles with genymotion: review FAQ Genymotions in https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions

---

If you see the log file of Genimotions you'll find this:

**VBoxManage.exe: error: 'Linux_64' is not a valid Guest OS type**

The problem is the version of Virtual Box, I thought I had the last version (4.2) because virtual box said me that it was the lastest version, but it wasn't true: The last version actually is 5.0.20

I've installed the last version (5.0.20), and ova is ok

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows:

The folder left after uninstallation is located at:

> C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\

**Before proceeding, in the OVA folder, save the ova files in there if you do not want to redownload the images all over again.**

1. Clear the Genymotion cache, and then uninstall Genymotion (and Oracle VBOX if needed)
2. Remove the whole Genymotion folder in the above path
3. Reinstall genymotion and VirtualBox
4. Copy back the ova files into the ova folder.
5. Re-add the virtual device accordingly (the ova files name should be identifiable easily enough)

Genymotion will then verify the integrity of the stuffs and should now works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just Run Genymotion with Administrator right (**run as Administrator**)! It work perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and also tried deleting the Genymotion cached .ova file and old images but to no avail.

To get my Genymotion working again in my environment I completely uninstalled VirtualBox and Genymotion using the TrashMe app to ensure no trace was left on my system. You can achieve the same result with the free app [App Cleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

I then completely deleted the ~/.Genymobile directory as this seems to get left behind when deleting/uninstalling Genymotion. I think this is the only thing I did differently this time.

I then re-downloaded the latest versions of VirtualBox and Genymotion and installed them in that order. (Versions at time of writing: VB - 4.3.13 r93733 / GM - 2.2.2)

I then launched Genymotion, connected to my account, added a new device and I am now back up and running.

Hopefully that helps..

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when my hard drive was almost full. It looked like it had enough space for the emulator, but Genymotion still failed with `failed to import eva`

Solved by freeing up a couple Gigs on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Updating  VirtualBox to the latest version, Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the virtual devices and cleared Cache. After that I added the device again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it with uninstalling, reinstalling and running Gennymotion with **Admin rights**. Make sure you **not upgrade** Oracle VM and use the one you installed with Genymotion. Also at installing Genymotion make sure you **reinstall VM** too. It should work, I lost my devices too and this method only solve the OVA problem. If you run the virtual device and get an error, **reboot** computer, if you didn't do after installing Oracle VM. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

it turns for me I restored the system from the backup

Click geny settings->virtualbox tab, have to correct the folder to keep the VM

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted /Users//.Genymobile/ directory and Genimotion started work fine

Answer (score 0):

[image]
make sure you choose the correct android sdk

Answer (score 0):

in Linux
just delete

> home/user/.config/Genymobile/Genymotion.conf

and it's work

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded ova that match with version i want (example android 5)

http://fatihcamuz.com/2015/04/download-links-of-genymotion-ova/

then add ova file to genymotion

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MiYhVUv4KE

Comment: please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.