# Genymotion cannot create virtual device.I get message" Unable to create virtual device : Failed to import OVA"

Tags: android, genymotion

I installed Genymotion. When I try to add some virtual device I get a message "Unable to create virtual device : Failed to import OVA".
I try to find find .ova files in ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion but deployed folder does not exist.
In ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion there is no .ova files.
My operating system is Windows 7 64 bit.
Hardware configuration is : Intel Core2 Duo, 4 GB RAM memory.

Comment: see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945709/geny-motion-failed-to-import-ova

Answer (score 1):

"I had the same problem and here's what the team answered me

Please delete this folder C:\Users\pvillalon\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Samsung Galaxy S3 - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280\ then try again. "

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here's what the team answered me

Please delete this folder `C:\Users\pvillalon\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Samsung Galaxy S3 - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280\` then try again.

Comment: After reading the question it looks like there was no `deployed` folder inside of `\Genymobile\Genymotion`.