# Genymotion "Unable to create virtual machine: failed to import ova file"

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation, genymotion

I know this question has been asked before but I have tried the answers listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168838/genymotion-cannot-create-virtual-device-i-get-message-unable-to-create-virtual) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945709/geny-motion-failed-to-import-ova) but nothing changed. I tried to re-install Genymotion and VirtualBox and run Genymotion as administrator, but nothing.

My problem is always the same: when I try to deploy a virtual device, Genymotion fails with the error message: "Unable to create virtual device: failed to import OVA file". Does anyone know of any solutions?

My specs:
OS - Windows 8.1
CPU - Intel Core i3 @ 2.3Ghz (quad-core)
RAM - 6GB DDR3
Disk - 500GB (with 400 GB left)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540311/unable-to-create-genymotion-virtual-device)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Open Genymotion with Run as Administrative(Administrative privilege)