# Does Genymotion require admin privileges?

Tags: windows, admin, genymotion

On a Surface Pro 3 with Win8.1, already have VirtualBox 5.0.6 installed (works fine with Linux images), just installed Genymotion 2.5.4.

Every time I try to start Genymotion, it asks for admin privileges to invoke something on VirtualBox.  Why does this need admin?  Any way to avoid this?

According to [Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540311/unable-to-create-genymotion-virtual-device) a number of people think it shouldn't and I can't find any reference on Genymotion's website that they need admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin privilege appears when Genymotion creates or configure network interfaces though VirtualBox. This network configuration is unfortunately mandatory for the software to work correctly.

The last changes on Windows and VBox obliges us to do it more frequently so that's the reason why you see it each time you start the program.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem with my non privileged user accounts using Windows 10.  When Genymotion runs for the first time as the current user, it will create a virtual interface if it does not see one defined in the users profile.  If your account has Administrator privileges, it will create the interface without issue.  As a non privileged user, you will get prompted for admin credentials so that a new virtual interface can be created and defined.

My workaround was to run Genymotion with an account that has administrator privileges so that the virtual interface is defined and the Genymotion interface starts up. After that, I preserve the following directories in:

C:\Users\%USERNAME%.VirtualBox and
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore

When I have a new user that needs to run Genymotion, I have them run a script that restores these directories to their profile. They can then run Genymotion without needing Admin credentials.