# How to download a device on genymotion?

Tags: genymotion

I get this error when I try to download a device on genymotion

> Error while creating the virtual terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540311/unable-to-create-genymotion-virtual-device)

Comment: no it is not the same problem

Comment: Can you look at the genymotion.log file and post its last few lines?. On Windows it is in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Genymobile. On macOS and Linux it is in ~/.Genymobile.